# How do I display a table on the home page in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a **class.js** that should output the table from `axios.get ('api/info/GetTableList ')`. But it draws it on a new page. How do I display a table on the home page?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export class Info extends Component {
    static displayName = Info.name;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { data: [] };}

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('api/info/GetTableList ').then((res) => {
            this.setState({ data: res });
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>IP</th>
                            <th>WRO</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.state.data.map(function (item, key) {
                            return (
                            <tr>
                                <td>{item.id}</td>
                                <td>{item.ip}</td>
                                <td>{item.wro}</td>
                            </tr>
                            )
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you missed something on your question.

Comment: From a code prospective everything looks fine. Your table should show on your `Info` component

Comment: it is displayed but loaded on top of the page, and the header goes away

Comment: it means that you have wrong app structure. You Header component should be on parent component. Or you can just insert header component before your table

Comment: See. When the page first loads, there is a header and < th>ID</th> < th>IP</th> < th>WRO</th>. After reloading by get the page will be updated without everything but with an array of the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use fetch insted of axios

```
async componentDidMount() {
   const res = await fetch(`api/info/GetTableList`)
   const data = await res.json();
   this.setState({
      data
   })
}
```

or you can use like this.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await fetch(
              `api/info/GetTableLis`,
              {
                method: "GET",
              }
            )
              .then(data => data.json())
              .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                  data
                });
              }),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is axios will return the response object, you need to get the `data` from the `response`

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('api/info/GetTableList ').then(({data=[]}) => {
        this.setState({ data});
    })
}
```

I have used shorthand syntax you can use the normal syntax

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('api/info/GetTableList ').then((res) => {
        this.setState({ data : res.data});
    })
}
```

Also please try logging the `res` like

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('api/info/GetTableList ').then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.setState({ data : res.data});
    }).catch(console.error)
}
```

please share the entire console log

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no effect ((And there is a way not to use axios or componentDidMount()

Comment: Could you try logging the response like
```jsx
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('api/info/GetTableList ').then((res) => {
       console.log(res)
        this.setState({ data : res.data});
    }).catch(e=>console.log(e))
}
```